# In Eclipse Find/Replace-field can i alter the regexp-matched result $1?

Tags: regex, eclipse, eclipse-3.4

I want to search and replace a lot of numbers in the range *0-9* and add one to them, so they become in the range *1-10* instead.

for example:
*0 3 5*

would become:
*1 4 6*

In eclipse Find/Replace window I can match a number with 
^([0-9]+)$

In the replace-field can I somehow add to the matched number $1?

/G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to specify a callback function/macro, which is what you would need in order to change the first group ($1), or any of the results, in such a way.

Maybe there's a plugin that will enable this, but I'm not currently aware of one.

As a work-around, you could perhaps use [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) for this, which does allow you to apply a script to your results (although I've not yet tried it myself so not sure how well it works).